# Command for Testing PC's Wifi Antenna

Tags: wireless-networking

I have an HP laptop that cannot find any wifi networks.  It can however connect to internet through ethernet.  It doesn't appear to be anything simple such as airplane mode, but I was wondering is there a command prompt command I can enter to check if the wifi antenna is functional and what its strength is? Not talking about the router/modem signal strength.

Comment: wifi antennas dont have strength.  It could be the antennas are not connected to the wifi card or a driver issue.

Comment: Try a USB wireless device to see if a new device works.

Comment: @davidgo is there a command to check for this?  A wireless mouse works

Comment: Your question needs more detail ie windows / Linux version and what have you already tried

Answer (score 1):

Wi-Fi strength from Taskbar

For Windows 10 first check the Wi-Fi signal strength by using the Wi-Fi icon in the Taskbar. The icon for the Wi-Fi in the Taskbar is dynamic and adjusts itself according to the Wi-Fi signal strength with the more curvy lines, the greater the signal strength. Each line represents 25 percent Wi-Fi signal strength.

The in built wireless network report is one of the more useful tools in Windows 10 that can help you diagnose Wi-Fi connection problems.
To create the wireless network report

1. In the search box on the taskbar, type Command prompt, press and hold (or right-click) Command prompt, and then select Run as administrator > Yes.
2. At the command prompt, type `netsh wlan show wlanreport`.

[microsoft support doc link](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/analyze-the-wireless-network-report-76da0daa-1db2-6049-d154-7bb679eb03ed)

To extract just signal strength as a percentage again from the elevated (administrator) command prompt type

```
netsh wlan show interfaces | ?{$_ -Match "Signal"}
```